Next js 14 multiple page layout problems
I get some troubles when I try to add another page for example admin page I get the same layout from the previous homepage layout so anyone know this please tell me how can I fix this one
I tried to use different layout for different page that's not working

Use route groups app/(publicRoute)/layout.tsx and app/(privateRoute)/admin/layout.tsx, these will appear in the browser with pathnames / and /admin, homepage and admin page will have different layouts

Corresponding docs link for @HairyHandKerchief23's comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Check out nextjs official documentation of the layout and template. Each page route has layout.tsx and page.tsx.
A layout is UI that is shared between multiple routes. On navigation, layouts preserve state, remain interactive, and do not re-render. Layouts can also be nested.
You can define a layout by default exporting a React component from a layout.js file. The component should accept a children prop that will be populated with a child layout (if it exists) or a page during rendering.
// app/dashboard/layout.tsx
export default function DashboardLayout({
  children, // will be a page or nested layout
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <section>
      {/* Include shared UI here e.g. a header or sidebar */}
      <nav></nav>
 
      {children}
    </section>
  )
}


try spitting your routes into groups
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#examples

HomePage
app/(homepage)/layout.js
app/(homepage)/page.js

admin
app/(admin)/layout.js
app/(admin)/page.js


